# PPA directory, Steam, Dota 2

Tags: graphics, ppa, steam

I have a graphics problem on Dota 2, the characters and the wood are transparent. When I'm starting steam I am adviced to install ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates 
However, when I type that in Terminal I get the message there is no such file or directory. I am new in Ubuntu 12.04, so any help would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

What they ask you to do is ...

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates 
sudo apt-get update
```

This will update all the software that that repository holds (and that includes dota2).

Comment: I did sudo apt-get update and it turned out that I had no sound on my computer. Being unable to fix that I had to reinstall Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

They advice you to add `ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates` repository, so the command will be :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
```

And then update the repository index :

```
sudo apt-get update
```

See also :

- [What are PPAs and how do i use them ?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)